# IF Statement Output in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query output:

[image]

The column "LesserValue" existed because of this if statement:

```
if((@RightD < @LeftD), 'RightD', 'LeftD') as LesserValue
```

It seems that it's not showing me the right output (@RightD is RightD column and @LeftD is LeftD column).

For the RightD and LeftD the query is:

```
@RightD := format(replace(@RDeduc,',','') - @Base, 2) as RightD,
@LeftD := format(@Base - replace(@LDeduc,',',''), 2) as LeftD,
```

Here's my complete test query:

```
select
distinct a.employee_number as EmployeeNumber,
employee_name as EmployeeName,
regular_days as GrossPay,
@TotalDeductions := ((lates + undertime) + absences) as TotalDeductions,
@Base := replace(`regular_days`,',','') - @TotalDeductions as Base,
@RDeduc := replace(format((select deduction from tbmonthlytax where deduction > @Base and status = employee_number_dependents order by deduction limit 1), 2),',','') as RDeduc,
@LDeduc := replace(format((select deduction from tbmonthlytax where deduction < @Base and status = employee_number_dependents order by deduction desc limit 1), 2),',','') as LDeduc,
@RightD := replace(format(@RDeduc - @Base, 2),',','') as RightD,
@LeftD := replace(format(@Base - @LDeduc, 2),',','') as LeftD,
if(@RightD < @LeftD, @RightD, @LeftD) as LesserValue
```

from
    tbpayslip a, tbemployee b

where
    a.employee_number = b.employee_number

Comment: is type of `@RightD` is `varchar` ?

Comment: Well I guess it is, because of the comma Anik Islam Abhi.

Comment: can you provide a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: When you apply a `format`, you're converting values to strings.  That's your problem.  The string 1753 comes before 330 in string-based sort order.

Comment: Oh ok. So what should I do to prevent it from converting to string? @Marc

Comment: Compare the unformatted values in your `if` statement.

Comment: Ok let me try that. I'll let you know once done.

Comment: @Marc It's still the same. I remove all formats.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer myself. ABS() solved my problem.

```
if(ABS(@RightD) < ABS(@LeftD), 'Right', 'Left') as LesserValue
```

I hope this can help you too.

Thank you guys.